# jquery jtable custom click event

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I have implemented jtable of jquery. I want to perform some operation on row click and also want to put separate image and also want to add my own click event on that image.

I also want to pass that row's id to that custom event.

How can I add that to jquery table?

I tried some stuffs.

```
LoadGrid = (function () {
            //Prepare jtable plugin
            $('#GridTableContainer').jtable({
                title: 'Assets',
                paging: true,
                pageSize: 10,
                sorting: true,
                defaultSorting: 'ModelName ASC',
                actions: {
                    listAction: '/Adminsec/ManageAssets.aspx/List',
                    createAction: '/Adminsec/ManageAssets.aspx/CreateOrUpdate',
                    updateAction: '/Adminsec/ManageAssets.aspx/CreateOrUpdate',
                    deleteAction: '/Adminsec/ManageAssets.aspx/Deletes'
                },
                updateRecord: (function() { alert("my custom action.");
                }),
.......
```

Comment: Yes, I know. I tried adding my own javascript code.   actions: {
                    listAction: my javascript code.  But it is not something worked for me.

Comment: I want to have my own updateAction. and want to add some code on it.

Comment: According to the [docs](http://www.jtable.org/ApiReference#met-updateRecord), `updateRecord` is a method, not an option.

Comment: @Pankucins - Check answer I posted below. I do not want any one to do for me. I am also here to help others. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally, Done.

```
CustomAction: {
    title: '',
    width: '1%',
    sorting: false,
    create: false,
    edit: false,
    list: true,
    display: function (data) {
        if (data.record) {
            return '<button title="Edit Record" class="jtable-command-button jtable-edit-command-button" onclick="alert(' + data.record.TicketId + '); return false;"><span>Edit Record</span></button>';
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: where you did add this on jtable defenition?

Comment: In Json properties itself. You can refer to jtable documentation for it.

Comment: Thank you for your tips but please send your total code of Jtable

Comment: Provided code is snipplet, full documentation with example you can find on jtable site itself.